# Sum up value from OnActivityResult

Tags: android, listview, sum, onactivityresult

I have a listview in Activity A. I want to sum up the total amount which are return from Activity B to Activity A, but I have no idea on how to add them up.

```
 double sum =0;

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
             double ReceiveAmount = data.getDoubleExtra("amount",0);
             sum = + ReceiveAmount;
            totalAmount.setText(sum+")
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Assume in Activity B I return amount 5, then I go to Activity B again and return value 10. I want the toast display value 15 instead of always 5.

**Edit**

```
   @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                   double ReceiveAmount = data.getDoubleExtra("amount",0);
                    sum += ReceiveAmount;
                    if (mClickedPosition == -1) {  // if icon clicked
                        if (obj != null) {
                            obj.addNewItem(ReceiveAmount);
                            listview.setAdapter(obj);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sum+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            addOrRemoveFooter(sum);
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }

  public void addOrRemoveFooter(double sum2) {
    if (search.size() == 0 && listview.getFooterViewsCount() > 0) {
        listview.removeFooterView(footerLayout);
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"In"+sum2+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (listview.getFooterViewsCount() == 0 && search.size() > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Out"+sum2+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        listview.addFooterView(footerLayout);
        listview.setAdapter(obj);
        totalAmount.setText(sum2 + "");
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The toast now display 15, but the setText always 5...Why ?

At first everything seems fine as it display `Out` in `addOrRemoveFooter`  `Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Out"+sum2+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`,but when I add the second time it display `error`.

Comment: It's `+=` and not `=+`.

Comment: @PrerakSola changed but still getting the same result

Comment: Update your new code with the exact error and the line of error.

Comment: @PrerakSola I just change `sum = + ReceiveAmount;` to `sum  += ReceiveAmount;`, but I still get the sum value as 5, not 15

Comment: You are also missing a `"` in your `setText` method.

Comment: @PrerakSola can you check my post again ?

Comment: are you sure it goes into the `else..if` block?

Comment: @PrerakSola yes..it goes to `else if`. I have checked that

Comment: @PrerakSola sorry,can you check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the add up problem, just change `=+` to `+=`

Answer (score 3):

First of all start your activity with startActivityForResult like this way.

```
private static final int RC_B = 123;
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);    
activityA.startActivityForResult(intent, RC_B);
```

then in Activity B override onFinish() and in onFinish

```
@Override
public void finish() {
  Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
  resultIntent.putExtra("total", 45);  // For Example.
  setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
  super.finish();
}
```

then after override onActivityResult in Activity A and put the code like below.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)         {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == RC_B) {
         // get your value of sum from intent
         total = intent.getIntExtra("total",0);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check my post again ?

Comment: If your toast displays correctly then textview value must be set to that text which is shown in Toast.

Comment: sorry,can you check again

Comment: Try to debug the app.It seems difficult to answer from the piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

Store your amount value in Sharedpreference. Sum up the value from preference each time you return to Activity A.

Comment: Where the Sharedpreference should be ? In Activity B ?

Comment: In your Activity A, onActivityResult, store that sum value in sharedpreference  each time. Also get data from sharedpreference and sum up with the amount .

Comment: can you check my post again ?

Comment: Your else if condition to update the textview value might not be triggered when sum becomes 15. Debug your app.

Comment: sorry,can you check again

Answer (score 1):

Make it variable sum static

```
public static double sum =0;
```

than add when ever and where ever you want in app and 
just display in onActivityResult no need to pass through intent (make sure reinitialize after use)

Comment: can you check my post again ?